# Detailed Big-Oh question

Tags: algorithm, analysis

So, I'm slightly confused by this question on my homework.

```
 for ( int j = 0; j < 2*n; j++){
for ( int k = 0; k < n * n * n; k += 3)
sum++;
}
```

So I am at this conclusion after a bit of confusion

for( 1, 2n, n)
for( 1/3( 1, 3n, 1)
I have it as 1/3 because it's going up by 3. I'm just not sure if I'm right, we were just introduced to this so I'm sorta lost.

Comment: What is your question? Also, you aren't using big-Oh notation at all in your question.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not completely sure that I understand what you are asking...  Assuming that the question is what the Big-O notation for this nested loop would be (and assuming that the addition operation is the base operation)

- The outer loop is executed `2n` times
- The inner loop is executed `n^3/3` times for each iteration of the outer loop

That means that the inner statement is executed `2n` * `n^3/3` = `(2/3)*n^4`.  For Big O notation, we ignore the constants, so this nested loop is O(n^4).

Comment: Um...I just had trouble figuring out the run times of each one. What is j < 2*n considered, just 2n?

Comment: The outer loop will execute `2n` times, yes.  Since we drop constants when we talk about Big O notation, that would become `O(n)`.